# Power Shell variable Assignment From XML File

Tags: powershell

PowerShell newbie with a question.

I have a test XML file:
`<FILE_INFO> <STATUS>NON-ACTIVE</STATUS> <TITLE>VICE-PRESIDENT</TITLE> <STARTDATE>11/12/13</STARTDATE> <ENDDATE>10/11/12</ENDDATE> </FILE_INFO>`

Using Windows PowerShell IDE, I can parse the XML data.

```
`$Data = Get-Content ./my_XML.xml
$Data.FILE_INFO`
```

This returns:

```
`STATUS     TITLE          STARTDATE ENDDATE
 ------     -----          --------- -------
NON-ACTIVE VICE-PRESIDENT 11/12/13  10/11/12`
```

And subsequently *$Data.FILE_INFO.STATUS* returns *NON-ACTIVE*, etc.

Why won't `$Data.FILE_INFO.STATUS` work within a script file (e.g. test_file.ps1)? Please enlighten this PowerShell beginner.

In my ps1 file, I put write-host statements to see what's happening, and I'm getting NULL variables.

```
`$Data = Get-Content ./my_XML.xml
[string]$Xml_Status = $Data.FILE_INFO.STATUS
[string]$Xml_Title = $Data.FILE_INFO.TITLE
[string]$Xml_StartDate = $Data.FILE_INFO.STARTDATE
[string]$Xml_EndDate = $Data.FILE_INFO.ENDDATE

write-host "DATA = $Data"
write-host "Xml_Status: $Xml_Status"`
```

I've tried the assignment statements with and without [string] - didn't expect a difference and didn't see a difference.

My end goal is to take the XML data (less tags, of course) and put them in a database.

Comment: `Get-Content` alone won't convert the returned text to parse-able xml. You need to type cast `xml` to it: `[xml]$Data = Get-Content ./....`.

Comment: Thanks for responding. My fault!!  I did try that, but it didn't put that into my original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your datatype for `$data` needs to be `xml` to allow you to work with the xml object rather than just a string

```
[xml]$Data = Get-Content ./my_XML.xml
[string]$Xml_Status = $Data.FILE_INFO.STATUS
[string]$Xml_Title = $Data.FILE_INFO.TITLE
[string]$Xml_StartDate = $Data.FILE_INFO.STARTDATE
[string]$Xml_EndDate = $Data.FILE_INFO.ENDDATE

write-host "DATA = $Data"
write-host "Xml_Status: $Xml_Status"
```

Comment: Thanks. Tried this, and am getting an error "Cannot convert value 
(xml file contents deleted here to save space) to the type "System.Xml.XmlDocument". Error: "The specified node cannot be inserted as the valid child of this node, because the specified node is the wrong type."